# XPath matching and get text value

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, continuous-integration

I currently have a problem to move my project into continuous integration.

I put in place a parameters.xml file that should overwrite the values ​​of the web.config file of the solution via getParameter files.

But on the whole configuration, I have two settings that are not updated after deployment because of their particular case.

Indeed, I try to access a text and not an attribute.
So I have this:

```
...<property name="connection.connection_string">Server=XXX\DEV;initial catalog=YYY;Integrated Security=ZZZ</property>...
```

and try to match and replace with this but the parameters aren't updated after déploiement

```
  <parameter
    name="nhibernate connection string"
    description="Please provide the nhibernate connection string."
    defaultValue="Server=XXX\DEV;initial catalog=YYY;Integrated Security=ZZZ">
    <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope="\\web.config$" match="/AAA/BBB/CCC/property[@name='connection.connection_string']/text()" />
  </parameter>
```

In SetParameters files I have

```
  <setParameter name="nhibernate connection string" value="Server=SSS\DD;initial catalog=XXX;Integrated Security=ZZZ" />
```

Thank for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are talking about Web Deploy parameters. And in your web.config, you have a `...<property name="connection.connection_string">...` element of which the value need to be changed by `setParameter` during deployment.

One problem I saw is the value of `scope` in your parameterEntry. It should be a regular expression. So to match web.config, `.` should be escaped like `\\web\.config$`. Also the path of the web.config should be its location in your package .zip file. You probably want to double check if the path matches the expression.

The XPath seems fine to me. But you may want to use some tools to verify if it works as expected or not against your web.config. There are many online tools which can do it, such as this one: http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm

A side note, if you just have some settings in web.config which are different for different environments, [web.config transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations) would be an easier and better way than Web Deploy to achieve the CI/CD.